# Updating data set with only new records R

Tags: r, xml, itunes

I currently have a function written in R that scrapes the 10 publically available pages iTunes displays app reviews on.

```
 nbc_reviews <- bind_rows(lapply(1:10, function(n) {getReviews(123456789,'us',n)}))
```

Column Headers are displayed as such:

"Title"   "Author_URL"  "Author_Name" "App_Version "Date"

Currently, every time the function runs, it replaces all the previous records with data from only the 10 most recent pages. I was wondering how could I update the dataset with only new entries so that I could collect information over time?

Comment: By "update the dataset with only new entries", do you mean append?

Comment: What about `nbc_reviews <- bind_rows(nbc_reviews, lapply(1:10, function(n) {getReviews(123456789,'us',n)}))` ?

Comment: @avid_useR Yes, I am trying to append rows that are not already in the table